# Hive Backup and Restore

Tags: hive, backup, cloudera, hortonworks-dataflow

I want to take a monthly / quarterly backup of both Hive metadata and Hive data at once for more than 1000 tables with easy restoring capability. So far, I found below options but not sure which is best for backing up Hive tables in production. Any tips ?

1. Apache Falcon - http://saptak.in/writing/2015/08/11/mirroring-datasets-hadoop-clusters-apache-falcon

- Pro: Easily available as a service in Ambari for install
- Con: No community support

2. Hortonworks Data flow - https://docs.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.4.0/bk_ambari-upgrade-major/content/prepare_hive_for_upgrade.html

- Pro: Latest
- Con: No much documentation to test. Please share any resources of how to backup with Hortonworks data flow

3. Other ways - Hive data backup With Distcp, Export/Import, Snapshots and hive metadata backup using relational database dumps

- Con: Not sure if both Hive data and Hive metadata get backed-up at same time. Time-taking to implement a monthly / quarterly scheduler.

Comment: For the third option Hive metadata usually dosn't take any concerning time.
with distcp:  size and how your data is partitioned/distributed  are the major factors of "Time-taking"

Comment: @Bilal thank you. I understand getting metadata dumps would be easier. Reg. size and partitions - 1000 tables some partitioned by column year and some by timestamp. Do you have any scheduler samples that implement metadata backup and hive data backup at the same time? Maybe backup has to be stored in compressed format for easy retrieval.

Comment: hello, you're welcome, sorry I do not have any samples right now to share, and I didn't try any compressed format otherwise it sounds like a great solution